# unable to return a value as an array after retriving from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a single value or all the values from the table in mysql using php, it works for single value and it is not the case for all the values, please help me.

```
function displaySitetype() {
    $result = array();
    $result = site_type_find("all");
    print_r($result);
    $count = count($result);
    for ($iter = 0; $iter < $count; $iter++) {
        ?> <option value="<?php echo $iter; ?>"><?php echo $result[$iter]; ?></option> <?php }
}

function site_type_find($site_type) {
    if ($site_type == "all") {
        $result = mysql_query("select * from site_type_table");
        $count = count($result);
        while ($count) {
            $resultarr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $arr = array_push($arr, $resultarr['site_name']);
            $count--;
        } return $arr;
    } else {
        $result = mysql_query("select site_name from site_type_table where site_id=$site_type");
        $arr = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        return $arr[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal fix: try the following (I suppose that you want only values for column `site_name`)

```
//...
if ($site_type == "all") {
    $result = mysql_query("select site_name from site_type_table");
    $arr = array();
    while ($resultarr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arr[] = $resultarr['site_name'];
    }
    return $arr;
} else {
//...
```

BTW, I would not recommend use of `mysql_*` functions ([deprecated in PHP 5.5+](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php))

Note that you cannot call `count()` directly on your variable $result (which is a reference to a MySQL query results). To get results count in your situation, you can use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) (check carefully the red warning box at the beginning on the man page)

Comment: Too many mistakes i have made out of working continuously, thank you saved me a lot of frustration.